# removeChild() not working using easeljs

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I am using easeljs to create a stage and then i am putting tiles on the stage on random locations. When the user clicks on a tile, the tile must be removed from the stage.
There are two problems that i am facing. First was that the mouse event was not working. The code "tile.onPress = (tileOnPress).bind(this);" so i used the addEventListener method instead. Now although the function is being called as i am getting the output on the console, the tile is not being removed from the stage.
Here is the code:

```
c99.Game = (function(){
function Count99Game() {
    console.log("Count 99 game starts");

    this.canvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');

    this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);

    var totalTiles = 10;

    var tileOnPress = function(event) {
        console.log("Pressed");
        this.stage.removeChild(event.target);
        this.stage.update();
    };  

    for (var i = totalTiles; i > 0; i--) {
        var tile = new c99.Tile(i);
        this.stage.addChild(tile);
        tile.x = Math.random()*(this.canvas.width - tile.width);
        tile.y = Math.random()*(this.canvas.height - tile.height);

        //tile.onPress = (tileOnPress).bind(this);
        tile.addEventListener("click", tileOnPress.bind(this));
    }

    this.stage.update();
}   

return Count99Game;
})();
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me why "tile.onPress = (tileOnPress).bind(this);" isn't working and also what changes need to be done in the tileOnPress function so that the tile that is pressed can be removed from the stage.

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/ZANTGames/count99/blob/master/js/count99-game.js

Comment: Would you provide a fiddle for this, not able to debug this code

Comment: Hello, here's the link to the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/g2xfmekL/3/

Comment: Actually you are using canvas and canvas is a set of pixels drawn... its not like objects that you can easily remove, One thing you can do is redraw the canvas again, I am looking for other solution aswell

Comment: I am adding the shapes to the stage using easeljs. Easeljs provides methods for adding as well as removing elements from the stage. To add i can simply use addChild() method and to remove i can use removeChild() method. But somehow the display object is not being able to be passed to the removeChild() method. Note that if i do removeAllChildren() then all the tiles will be removed from the stage

Comment: hmmm removeAllChildren is working, so there should be a way, may be we are missing something

Comment: Try this.stage.removeChildAt(1) if you know index of child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
this.stage.removeChild(event.target.parent)
```

This is because event.target is shape and its parent is tile and basically you want to remove the tile so this is working

For your future reference I have found it from this documentation
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html

Comment: I tried.. but i need 15 reputation for that :P 
Will upvote it as soon as i get a reputation of 15

Comment: Ohhh i didn't knew that

Comment: You can also use `mouseChildren` on the parent to aggregate the child events onto the parent.